# Grails 2.5.1 Restful controller spock unit test fails with 406 when running in Intellij IDEA

Tags: rest, unit-testing, grails, intellij-idea, spock

I have set up a test app on bitbucket that reproduces my issue:

https://bitbucket.org/LuisMuniz/grails-bug-notacceptable

I have fairly standard REST controller action (save) that returns a http response status of 201 (CREATED).

- When I run a functional test, everything works out as expected, with a http status of 201.
- When I run a unit test standalone, with grailsw, the controller behaves as expected, returning code 201.
- When I run the same unit test inside Intellij IDEA (tried with latest 14.x and latest 15 EAP versions), the controller returns http code 406 (NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

I have debugged the test execution and have found that it comes to the mimeTypes inside the applicationContext, that only contain a single entry: text/html.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this a known issue?

Is there a way to fix this or else is there something I can do to make Intellij unit tests not fail or maybe use a Junit Rule to skip these tests if they are executed in Intellij?

**Update**
Upon demand, posting the code here.

```
package na

import grails.rest.RestfulController
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus

class MyController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json']
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST"]

    def save() {
        response.status=HttpStatus.CREATED.value()
        respond request.JSON
    }
}
```

Functional test (this passes):

```
package na

import grails.util.Holders
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import spock.lang.Specification
import wslite.rest.RESTClient
/**
 * Created by lmuniz on 17/09/15.
 */
class MyControllerFuncSpec extends Specification {
    def "Controller returns status 201"() {
        given:
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        def restClient = new RESTClient("http://localhost:8080/notacceptable")

        when:
        def response = restClient.post([path: "/my"]) {
            json payload
        }

        then:
        response.statusCode == HttpStatus.CREATED.value()
        response.json == payload

        where:
        payload = [message: "Hello world"]
    }
}
```

Unit Test (fails in IDEA):

```
package na

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {
    boolean runsInIntellij() {
        System.getProperty('idea.launcher.port') != null
    }

    @Unroll
    def "Controller responds with http code #expectedResponseCode when it is running #inEnvironment"(){
        given:
        println System.getProperties().collect {it.toString()}.join('\n')

        request.method = 'POST'
        request.json = [message:"Hello world"]

        when:
        controller.save()

        then:
        response.status == expectedResponseCode

        where:
        expectedResponseCode = (runsInIntellij() ? NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value() : CREATED.value())
        inEnvironment = (runsInIntellij() ? 'inside Intellij' : 'standalone')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, instead of

> respond request.JSON

Can you try with this:

> render(status: response.status)

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround, but that is not what I am after. I want to be able to use the content negotiation strategies built into respond. This is an issue that only happens when running tests inside Intellij IDEA, I don't want to change my production code because of that!